# Windows 7 local area connection switches to disable after reboot

Tags: windows-7, home-networking

I need help to keep my PC (Windows 7) connected to the net. I've found out how to get back on the Net by changing my local area connection from disable to enable. But the connection switches back to disable after I startup or reboot my PC. Does anybody know what I have to do to keep the settings enable?

Comment: can you please provide more details? has this problem always been there? if not, when and how did it start?
in the meantime, just put a batch file to enable the LAN into startup. A simple google will get you how to write that batch.

Comment: Thanks tumchaaditya for your response! I’m not quite sure when the connection problem started. I’m guessing I must have stuffed something up while I tried to upgrade Adobe CS3 to CS5 (both legitimate). CS5 regNo. was accepted but not CS3  which was on my PC over 3 years. I reinstalled CS3 with quite a bit of trouble and pretty much from there on I could not connect to the internet. 
Creating a batch file sounds like a good idea. I searched the web for info but it all sounds a  bit over my capabilities. Do you know a site with instructions that are easy to understand for  a beginner?

Comment: go here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/simple-way-disable-enable-lan-command-prompt-batch-file-using-devcon-exe-t2501814.html

read the post by pegasus. he has posted a batch file. just replace the network adapter name as it appears in control panel.

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves writing a batch file to enable LAN and running it at system startup.
Its not the best way. But, definitely better than having to go through reinstallations.

**Step 1 - Get devcon**

Download devcon.exe from here:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f7dd10-272d-4cd2-896f-9ce67f3e0240/devcon.exe

Put the devcon.exe in same dir as batch file.

**Step 2 - Obtain adapter name**

Go to control panel > network and sharing center.
Click on change adapter settings in left pane.

Locate the LAN connection with problem and note the adapter name.
It is something like `Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet`

Alternatively, you can go to command prompt and use `ipconfig /all`

Locate the LAN connection and note the "Description" for that. The description is nothing but adapter name.

**Step 3 - the batch file**

Now that you have adapter name, put it in this batch file:

```
@echo off
goto Start

rem Use this batch file to enable or disable a device
rem from the Command Prompt.

:Start
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Adapter=<PUT YOUR ADAPTER NAME HERE>

if /i "%1"=="enable" goto go
if /i "%1"=="disable" goto go
echo Syntax: Device enable / disable
goto :eof

:go
set HWID=x
set count=0
set found=no

devcon hwids "PCI\*" > device.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%* in (device.txt) do (
set /a count=!count! + 1
if /i "%%*"=="Name: %Adapter%" set found=yes& set count=1
if !found!==yes if !count!==3 set HWID=%%*
)
if %found%==yes (
echo HWID=!HWID!
devcon %1 "!HWID!"
) else (
echo Device "%Adapter%" not found.
)
endlocal
del device.txt
```

Save as some abc.bat & test the batch file.

Syntax to use the batch is:

```
abc.bat enable
```

If it works, then schedule it to run at startup.

Comment: Problem solved. Running fine now. MANY THANKS